# OOP: exampe and references on constructor anomalies

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, object-oriented

I have read the following artice that defines the term "constructor anomaly":

Cohen, Tal, and Joseph Gil. "Better Construction with Factories." journal of object technology 6.6 (2007): 103-123.
http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2007_07/article3/

Where can I find examples and references on constructor anomalies? (also in the context of multiplie inheritance)

Are constructor anomalies always due to a method call in the constructor or is it possiple to construct an example without method calls in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Constructor anomaly" is not a bug or anything; it is simply an anomaly on the classification of constructor functions. ie. constructor functions are different from member functions in the following ways.

Anomalous classifications:

- While most member functions require an instance and work on an instance, a constructor does not require an instance, but still works on an instance:

  ```
    f.bar(); // instance of f, can call bar(). bar() does stuff to/with f.

    new F(); // no instance, yet called F::F(). Yet F::F() does works on an instance.
  ```
- Most member functions can replace or extend their base-class functions with the same name; that is, a member function can entirely override a base-function (replacement), ...   *or* ... it can override, and call the base function as well (extension). However, the constructor (in these languages) *must* extend, that is, call the base-class constructor first. (This is to delegate the base-class's construction to the base-class, first, and then construct the derived class):

  ```
  struct F{
      F(){/*stuff*/}
      virtual void bar(){/*stuff*/}
      virtual void baz(){/*stuff*/}
  };
  struct G : public F{
      virtual void bar()
      {
        //Do stuff
        F::bar(); // extend F::bar()
        //Do more stuff
      }
      virtual void baz()
      {
        //Do stuff
        //Do more stuff
        //No call to F::baz(), replaced it
      }
      G::G(){
        //this MUST extend F::F(); in C++ F() is called implicitly in this case.
        //However, if F() takes parameters, it must be called explicitly
      }
  };
  ```
- Most member functions can be dynamically bounded; that is, you never know if a (virtual) function `F* f; f->bar()` is calling `F::bar()` or if `f` is a type that derived from `F`; and thus a different `bar` is being called. However, constructors are *always* static, you must know exactly which class you are creating when you create it:

  ```
  H* h = get_h();
  h->bar(); // this function can be H::bar(), or anything defined in the virtual table; hence it is dynamic; h can be any derivative of H, overriding H::bar().


  F* f = new F(); // the call to F::F() MUST be (statically) linked to F(), not a derivative of F
  ```

Comment: great answer! do you know an example where calling bar or baz in the constructor (say in F) can lead to a NullPointer-Exception? Say G introduces a new field "person" of Type Person. The repaced method baz in G accesses this field and assumes this field is initialised with an instanciated Object. The G constructor is called and at the beginning the F constructor is called, this calls baz, this accesses the new field allthough the G constructor has not yet been fully executed to initialize the "person" field and thus causing a NullPointer Exception. (I think in Java terms but hope it is clear)

Comment: @mrsteve I am pretty sure calling virtual functions in a ctor is a no-no in C++ for this very reason.

Comment: I tested the mentioned example in Java and indeed a NullPointer exception is thrown. So in C++ there is no Problem but in Java it is the case! Thank you for your answer it helped me to understand the topic!

Comment: @mrsteve in C++ there *is* a problem; see [Do not invoke virtual functions from constructors or destructors](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/OOP30-CPP.+Do+not+invoke+virtual+functions+from+constructors+or+destructors). The only difference is, there are no `NullPointerException`s in C++, and it will happily keep running your program and randomly crash if it wants to (consequence of undefined behavior).